# Is this grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

> There's a precedent for well-bred girls addicted to the paranormal.

I get the feeling that after the 'girls' you should say 'to have addicted' instead of the past verb 'addicted'.

And if you want to stick to the 'addicted', you should switch 'precedent for' into 'precedent of'. Then we can see 'addicted' as a past participles, not a verb.

Am I right? If not, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "full" sentence is:

> There's a precedent for well-bred girls **who are** addicted to the paranormal

---

Hopefully I am not (very) wrong about the difference "precedent for / of".

You will use "**precedent for**" when you intend to describe a situation which can have a precedent.

> There is a **precedent for** crime.

You will use "**precedent of**" when you want to give an example of a precedent.

> There is a **precedent of** a president having an affair with an employee.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is fine.

The structures like

> There is a precedent **for** *somebody* **who** ...
>
> There are (several) precedents **for** *somebody* **who** ...

are pretty common.

> There's a precedent **for** *well-bred girls* (**who** are) addicted to the paranormal.